# grep and directories containing spaces

Tags: shell, grep, filenames, command-substitution

I would like to search all files containing an association of strings (here the files should contain 'arthur' AND ('déni' OR 'deni') for instance) in a directory and subdirectories. After some search I came up with the following code:

```
egrep -li 'arthur' `egrep -lir 'déni|deni' /path/to/files/`
```

the trouble is I get error messages because many files and directories contain spaces. Is there a way to go round this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be better off using `find` and passing a shell command to `-exec`:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -exec sh -c 'for file do
    egrep -iq "déni|deni" "$file" && egrep -li "arthur" "$file"
    done' sh {} +
```

This would work with filenames containing spaces.

Dissecting the shell command:

```
egrep -iq "déni|deni" "$file" && egrep -li "arthur" "$file"
```

Saying `egrep -iq "déni|deni" "$file"` would return *true* if the pattern matches.  So it would execute `egrep -li "arthur" "$file"` which would list the file if *this* command matches the pattern specified.

In fact, you don't even need a shell:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -exec egrep -iq "déni|deni" {} \; \
                            -exec egrep -li "arthur" {} \;
```

(`-exec` predicates with the `;` terminator can also be used as conditions (based on the exit status of the executed command)).

Comment: You have to quote this differently - the `|` will be interpreted as a pipe in the local shell as it stands.

Comment: @Graeme The quoting should be fixed now.

Comment: ok. I am not good enough to make the difference between both command but it seems that using the find command is quicker than egrep. So I'm gonna use that one.

Comment: @Jean, this will be slower than just using `egrep`/`xargs` as you will have 1-2 `egrep` processes per file. The advantage of this is that it is more portable, ie will work on a Mac etc.

Comment: @jejuba - Graeme's solutions is probably the better of the two.

Answer (score 5):

With GNU grep you can use the `-Z` option to null separate the filenames before piping to `xargs`:

```
egrep -lirZ 'déni|deni' /path/to/files/ | xargs -0 egrep -li 'arthur'
```